# Angular: Should static content be cached?

Tags: html, asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, caching

Should static content be cached for angularjs application? 
Calls for dynamic html templates every time makes the application slow as it waits for the dynamic html template file.

Specifically, should I add the following to my WebConfig setting?

```
<clientCache cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="60.00:00:00" />      <!--Cache Static content for 60 days-->
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use $templateCache to store your templates/views. They will be part of your js code.

If you are using gulp or grunt to build your javascript code, then you can setup task which will get all your html files and create js file (inside you will have all your views added to $templateCache) which you can reference in your index.html

https://thinkster.io/templatecache-tutorial

Gulp plugin for $templateCache

https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-angular-templatecache

Comment: Thanks. However, would static content caching as mentioned in my question achieve the same result?